# $C \subset V$ convex $\Rightarrow$ $C$ locally connected

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Let $C$ a subset of a normed vector space $V$.

Then it is straightforward that :

> $C$ is convex $\Rightarrow$ $C$ is connected,

and this result is cited everywhere.

But it is also true that :

> $C$ is convex $\Rightarrow$ $C$ is locally connected.

Here is the proof.

Suppose $C$ is convex, let $x \in C$ (if $C = \varnothing$ the statement is of course true), and $U$ an open set of $C$ containing $x$. We can write $U = U' \cap C$ where $U'$ is an open set of $V$. Since $U$ contains $x$, $U'$ contains $x$. Therefore there exists $r > 0$ such that $B(x,r) \subseteq U'$. Then $B(x,r) \cap C \subseteq U$. $B(x,r) \cap C$ is a convex set (as an intersection of two convex sets), open in $C$, and contains $x$, so it does the job. Hence $C$ is locally connected.

---

However, there seems to be no reference about the second result on the internet. The Wikipedia article on [locally connected spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_connected_space) doesn't mention it.

Two questions :

> 1. Is the result or my proof wrong (which I highly doubt) ?
> 2. Does someone know about a reference that mentions the result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof looks correct to me.

I don't know of any reference, but if there is one it will be some kind of textbook. Honestly, the result is really easy to prove, so there will certainly not be a paper dedicated to it. Maybe some articles use this, but I don't think you will find any kind of "standard reference" for this result.

Comment: Another way to prove it is to note that path-connected implies connected: If  $C$ is convex , $x\in C,$ and $y,z \in C\cap B(x,r)$ then the "line-segments" joining $y$ and $z$ to $x$ are subsets of $C\cap B(x,r).$ We can define a path from $y$ to $z$ from the union of these two "segments" .